# Где взять полный актуальный список всех стандартных параметров для функции add_theme_support?

Tags: wordpress

Где взять полный актуальный список всех стандартных параметров для функции `add_theme_support`?

Например, возможность `customize-selective-refresh-widgets` в докблоке к функции `add_theme_support` указана (`@since 4.5.0 The "customize-selective-refresh-widgets" feature was added`), а в исходном коде функции я строчку `customize-selective-refresh-widgets` найти не могу.

Comment: Зачем отсылать людей в гугл, когда они оттуда пришлю сюда))) Задача проекта, чтобы люди из гугла переходили к ответам, а не наоборот

Comment: @mihdan спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

У функции `add_theme_support()` два параметра — название добавляемой возможности (строка `$feature`) и дополнительные параметры для этой возможности (массив `$formats`).

У каждой возможности — свои дополнительные параметры. Поэтому их надо искать в описаниях самих возможностей:

1. Раздел [«Features»](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#features) в официальной документации разработчика.
2. Раздел [«Новые возможности»](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_theme_support#post-formats) на сайте wp-kama.ru

Comment: Да, я знаю про источники, где всё это можно посмотреть. Но вопрос возник потому, что список возможностей в исходном коде этой функции не полностью совпадает со списками из различных источников, включая и официальные.

Comment: @eav Если добавите в вопрос пример возможности. которая предусмотрена в коде, но не указана в документации, проблема станет и понятнее, и интереснее.

Comment: Этот список периодически меняется, особенно все, что с кастомайзером - это относительно новое всё. Парни обсуждают что-то в слеке, реализуют в виде плагина, потом хором тестят, привлекая обычных юзеров через плагин Beta Tester и, если все ровно, интегрируют в ядро. Когда тут писать документацию в Кодексе, когда еле успевают DocBlock оформить в коде. Кодекс устаревает очень быстро, особенно его русскоязычная версия. Поэтому надо смотреть их девресурс - https://developer.wordpress.org/, ну и инспектить код ядра - там самое актуальное добро